# How can I create a logger for a JavaScript arrow function?

Tags: javascript, logging, arrow-functions

Is there a way to implement a logger function that can intercept arrow functions like the example below? I

Original code:

```
const arrowFunctionExample = (value)=> {
    console.log('arrowFunctionExample',value)
}

function main(){
    arrowFunctionExample('testing')
}
```

New code:

```
const arrowFunctionExample = (value) => {
  console.log('arrowFunctionExample', value)
}

function main() {
  logger(arrowFunctionExample('testing'))
}

//something like this
const logger = (fn) => {
  console.log('logger', fn)
  if (typeof fn === 'function') {
    fn(value)
  }
}
```

I want to get the same effect when main execution in both cases, without having to edit the arrows functions.

Comment: As far as I know, `const main()` is not how you declare a `main` function.

Comment: `value` is undefined in your `logger`

Comment: If you want to get the same effect with or without the logger function, then why would you add it at all? What effect *do* you want to get from the logger function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that what you want ?

```js
function logger(fn){
    return function(){
        console.log("log:", fn.name, arguments);
        return fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}

const arrowFunctionExample = (value)=> {
    console.log("do something with", value);
};

function main(){
    logger(arrowFunctionExample)('testing')
}

main();
```